# What has been done to provide security for remote wireless updating of in-aircraft software components?

Tags: boeing, security, software

Is it true that in the latest generation of Boeing aircraft some software components / Electronic Flight Bag data can be pushed to the flight remotely via a Wireless link?

If so, what sort of safeguards are in place to preserve the integrity of such an update? How does the aircraft authenticate that the data sent is indeed legitimate?

I'm curious to know the details. e.g. Are these conventional Ethernet networks over which the update gets pushed at the airport end? Is the final wireless transmission done by a COTS WiFi router? Does the update travel via the internet from (say) Boeing till the airport?

Comment: "*I'm curious to know the details*": Not sure the designers want to satisfy your curiosity and help you start searching for the possible weaknesses. Even if hiding things is not a security, it sometime helps.

Comment: @mins Oh, I'm pretty sure the designers don't want to. But others often can. :) Peter Kampf did to some extent already. There might be other knowledgeably sources like him. It is amazing how much you can glean from anecdotal sources sometimes.

Comment: @mins Yes, I admit hiding things can sometimes help, but when it comes to something as critical as an aircraft the right way to do things IMO is to have better strategies than obscurity. You want to be more sure than PIAs & NDAs to protect your channels. I think security through obscurity is OK for things like toilet master lock opening buttons e.g. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24054/could-the-cabin-crew-open-the-lavatory-door-from-outside-when-someone-locked-the but not for critical stuff like avionics software updates.

Comment: @mins One key issue is how the aircraft system verifies that the patch it is getting over the air is a valid, un-tampered one? Is there a hardware based key verification module in the aircraft?

Comment: Also, holes are constantly being found in home / enterprise network setups. But then again, typically none of these domains are designed to the exacting standards of reliability that we have incorporated into aircraft by regulation.

Comment: @mins To put it another way: Whether it makes sense for the designers to rely on obscurity for security is their call. But OTOH flyers / pilots / technologists can still have an interest in knowing how the system works to be able to independently assess it without having to have blind faith in the design.

Comment: I understand, but you miss the point of how security and authenticity and eavesdropping are managed in general. Crypto keys are not secure if you are able to get a large computing power, this is why their length is increased from time to time. Just consider this fact and how it is similar to obscurity. The only way to be sure to detect data tampering by a "man in the middle" is, to my best knowledge, [quantum links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography), and be sure it won't be used in the aviation industry in the short term.

Comment: @mins Isn't something like a 2048 bit key reasonably secure even against the likes of a nationally owned supercomputer? By most estimates against any sort of scaling in CPUs, save quantum computing?

Comment: @mins I thought Man In The Middle Attacks can be 100% prevented by previous transfer of a key via a secure channel. e.g. If the hardware key was transferred from Boeing to the aircraft owner (say) by hand then the aircraft can be secure that and data update signed by that key is secure?

Comment: Any example I could give is a known threat (hence it has countermeasures) that may give a false feeling of how much we are in control. Anyway [ARP poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) is an example of making ciphering useless. Also you may remember the [goto fail](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) bug that left Apple devices exposed to SSL easy hacking for years. If you want more facts, then this has to be in a chat session, to comply with SE guidelines we already broke.

Comment: @curious_cat [Amount of simple operations that is safely out of reach for all humanity?](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6149/2138) on the [security.se] SE might be of interest.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: While a huge power seems required to break encryption, in practice keys [are not distributed equally](https://factorable.net/) for some pseudo-random number generators. [Weaknesses exist in the crypto standards](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10486/does-microsoft-use-dual-ec-drbg-by-default). Theoretical security is one thing, practical implementation is another.

Comment: @curious_cat wrote *"If the hardware key was transferred from Boeing to the aircraft owner by hand ...."*  They don't even need to do that.  Boeing ***built*** the plane.  They can install the certificate in the computer while they're still building the plane!  They know what certificate is installed, and can use a unique, known certificate for every plane in existence.

Answer (score 6):

Boeing claims in [this document](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/787_ground_wireless_system.pdf):

> The 787 uses wireless (802.11 b/g) technology while at the gate to
>   transfer maintenance data and update the Electronic Flight Bag (EFB).
>   This is referred to as “e- Enabling” and it will allow airlines flying
>   the 787 to operate more efficiently.

So, yes, they use a regular WLAN connection for transmitting data while on the ground.

The document continues:

> Upon weight on wheels the 787 attempts to authenticate specific ground
>   access points. Information regarding the key configuration
>   requirements and how the 787 authentication occurs requires the
>   signing of a PIA.

I interpret PIA as Proprietary Information Agreement, a form of secrecy agreement. Boeing uses [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) to safeguard the integrity of the connection.

If you want to know more, Boeing advises to contact 787terminalwireless@boeing.com. However, I doubt they will talk to you or me unless we are airport representatives with a credible need to know.

Comment: Ha! That's the worst kind of security & is exactly what I feared. I'm hoping that the grapevine will reveal more details. There must be a ton of people at airports exposed to this which unfortunately makes it neither secure nor obscure.

Comment: You only have to review the Stuxnet saga to see how security through obscurity works in practice for mission critical equipment.

Comment: @curious_cat I don't see what is wrong with adding security through obscurity to an otherwise secured system.

Comment: @DeltaLima, security through obscurity does not stop the serious attacks, but it stops the less serious ones and the white hats and security researchers, but you _want_ those to test the system to warn you about vulnerabilities before the serious attackers abuse them.

Comment: @JanHudec That is a fair point.

Comment: @JanHudec Well said!

Comment: Don't they have to reveal some of this info. to the FAA for certification? And once done, they ought to be more accessible for the rest of us. Actually, how much of this comes under the ambit of FAA certification? Where's the boundary line between systems that need FAA certification and ones that don't? e.g. Would the WLAN and specific protocols used to push updates and verify updates be subject to FAA oversight?

Comment: @curious_cat "exactly what I feared".  What is your fear?  You seem to assume that some obscurity is the **only** security, which it is not.  It is simply yet another layer which, as others have pointed out, is just a case of "why make it easier".  They are not using open internet and standard protocols here.  It's not a system a script kiddie or anonymous no-friends cyber-psychopath can just break into.  Also, they key, safety critical systems cannot be updated "over the air".  They have replaceable cards and in some cases, plugin updates which require physical access.

Comment: @Simon How to distribute software securely over potentially hostile networks is a fairly simple, well understood problem with multiple effective solutions in commercial (and non-commercial!) use. If the update channel _were_ secure in such a way, its details could be published in the New York Times and updates would remain secure. The very _existence_ of the PIA calls the overall security of the system into question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know, I'm a software engineer :), and I use government secure PIAs all the time.  You contradict yourself by saying that there are multiple effective solutions for comms in hostile environments (and I agree), but then question the system used since it involves a PIA.  The key point is that the aircraft "firmware" cannot be update using this system, which can only be achieved with physical access.  The insecurity of using iPads and the like for flight bags is already established.

Answer (score -1):

In theory, they are just transmitting data, not code updates to the aircraft. So, the worst-case scenario would be that somebody would replace a chart with fake chart or something like that, which would be a nuisance but should not affect the safety of the flight.

As a matter of routine, *any* radio link should be considered an inherently insecure mode of communication, because it is open, unlike wire connections which can be physically isolated and secured against intercept.

Of course, if there is a bug or weakness in their system somewhere, it might be possible for a hacker to "pierce the veil" and somehow modify a live system. Whether that is possible or not depends entirely on the system architecture and implementation details of the software in question. Without knowing this (highly proprietary) information it is impossible to know whether such a weakness exists.

The official guidance on practices is contained in various FAA circulars, notably FAA advisory circular (AC) 20-153.

Here is a paper describing the general security situation: [FAA Aircraft Systems Security](http://www.cabaa.com/documents/FAA_Aircraft_System_Information_Security_Protection_Overview_4-1-2015_Jim_Skaves.pdf).

Only the 787 is able to load actual flight system modules remotely, I believe, although as mentioned above many aircraft can wirelessly retrieve flight bag info. How Boeing verifies that a module is valid before loading I do not know, but in all likelihood they use a cryptographic certificate. If this is the case, then a hacker would either have to steal the cryptographic keys from Boeing, or find a bug in how they were using the certificate, in able to introduce a false module to the aircraft.

Comment: Are you sure no code updates are pushed over wireless? From what I remember the Wireless link is also proposed to be used to push Loadable Software Airplane Parts. That sounds like code.

Comment: Wired connections are no more secure than wireless if you are determined.  There exists equipment to intercept traffic on wired networks with no physical access from tens of metres away.  Really secure installations use [specially designed buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename)) to mitigate this.

Comment: @abelenky You would use encryption to prevent industrial espionage, among other things.